# CRC8 calculation with initialization

Tags: crc

I am new to CRC8 calculation. But I want to perform CRC8 calculation with initial `0xFF`. I have no idea how to use this initial 0xFF. Earlier, I was using this method as mentioned in `"Error Detection With CRC"` in http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/Notes/Networks/data.polynomial.html.
My `Msg Data is :8012h` and `Frame is 12D`.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't quite know why you want an initial `0xff` or what it's for.  You should read [Ross](http://www.ross.net/crc/crcpaper.html) [William's](https://ia600900.us.archive.org/24/items/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt) [excellent](http://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt) [CRC](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v3.html) [tutorial](http://www.info-system.ru/library/algo/crc1.pdf), which will give you a grounding in CRCs.  (I provided five different links for the same article, in case the stackoverflow police come around complaining about stale links in answers.  The last one is in Russian, just for kicks.)

You need to provide more information about what CRC-8 you are trying to generate.  Are you trying to match some standard?  What standard?  Some interface?  What interface?

Comment: Thanks... but I wish the pdf was in English

Comment: The other four links are in English.